# Error Cannot read property en quiz Game con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Lo que pasa es que me encontraba probando mi `quiz` este código pero resulta que llega a la parte final del `quiz` cuando le doy en el botón de ver resultados, y en la consola de chrome me aparece un error  realmente no se como solucionarlo soy nuevo en esto de programación , y tengo muy poca experiencia discúlpenme si de pronto mi código tiene cosas desagradables , les agradezco un montón , este es el error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
>       at arrays (index.js:93)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (index.js:175)

```js
var fill= [{

 "title":"QUESTION 1",
 "question": "The first mechanical computer designed by charles was called ?",
 "option1": "Abacus",
 "option2": "Processor",
 "option3": "System",
 "option4": "truue",
 "answer": "1"
}, {
    "title":"QUESTION 2",
 "question": "Which of the following is the most powerful type of computter",
 "option1": "Supermicro",
 "option2": "Supercomputer",
 "option3": "Superconductor",
 "option4": "Megaframe",
 "answer": "2"
},
{

    "title":"QUESTION 3",
 "question": "The first mechanical computer designed by charles was called ?",
 "option1": "Abacus",
 "option2": "Processor",
 "option3": "System",
 "option4": "truue",
 "answer": "3"
}, {

 "title":"QUESTION 4",
 "question": "Which of the following is the most powerful type of compuuter",
 "option1": "Supermicro",
 "option2": "Supercomputer",
 "option3": "Superconductor",
 "option4": "Megaframe", 
 "answer": "1"
},
{

 "title":"QUESTION 5",
 "question": "Which of the following is the most powerful type of compuuter",
 "option1": "Supermicro",
 "option2": "Supercomputer",
 "option3": "Superconductor",
 "option4": "Megaframe",
 "answer": "1"
}
]

/*this remove the the start of quiz and change color to principal contain*/
//variables contain
//
let body       = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let first      = document.getElementById("first");
let contenedor = document.getElementsByClassName("contenedor")[0];
let question   = document.getElementsByClassName("question")[0];
let title      = document.getElementById("title");
let paragraph  = document.getElementById("redact");
let option1    = document.getElementById("option1");
let option2    = document.getElementById("option2");
let option3    = document.getElementById("option3");
let option4    = document.getElementById("option4");
let message    = document.getElementById("message");
let button     = document.getElementById("start");
let check      = document.getElementById("check");
let next       = document.getElementById("next");
let input = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs input[type="radio"]');

let actualQuestion = 0;
let points         = 0;
let numQuestions   = fill.length;

body.addEventListener('load',start(),false);

function start(){

question.style.display = 'none';

// listener button
button.addEventListener('click',function(){

first.style.display = 'none';
contenedor.style.background = '#FFA54F';
question.style.display = 'block';
next.disabled=true;

});
}

function arrays(index){

  let quest= fill[index];
  title.textContent= quest.title;
  paragraph.textContent= quest.question;
  option1.textContent= quest.option1;
  option2.textContent= quest.option2;
  option3.textContent= quest.option3;
  option4.textContent= quest.option4;
  

}

function nextQuestion(){


let choose = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
let imageCorrect = document.getElementById("correct");
let imageWrong= document.getElementById("wrong");




if(!choose){
  message.style.display = 'block';
  message.textContent= "Please answer the question";
  message.style.marginTop="20px";
  message.style.fontSize= "0.8em"; 
   
}

let value = choose.value;

if(fill[actualQuestion].answer==value){
    
   imageCorrect.style.display="block";
   disabledInputs()

   points+=20;
}else{

   imageWrong.style.display = 'block';
   disabledInputs()
}

if((choose.checked=true)){
   
   message.style.display ="none";
   next.disabled=false;
}

choose.checked=false;

++actualQuestion;



if(actualQuestion==numQuestions){
    
    next.textContent="Result";
    next.addEventListener("click",function(){

    let result = document.getElementById("result");
    let score = document.getElementById("score");
    question.style.display = 'none';
    contenedor.style.background="#FFAE75";
    result.style.display="block";
    score.textContent="Your score "+points;

    })

}

next.addEventListener('click',function(){



next.disabled=true;
imageWrong.style.display="none";
imageCorrect.style.display="none";
activeInputs()

arrays(actualQuestion);

})

}
function disabledInputs(){

  for(let i=0 ; i<input.length;i++){
 
  input[i].disabled=true;  
}

}
function activeInputs(){

  for(let i=0 ; i<input.length;i++){
 
  input[i].disabled=false;
   
}
}
arrays(actualQuestion);

check.addEventListener('click',nextQuestion)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt|VT323');

h1{

  font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E5A46A, grey);
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

h2{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.contenedor{

font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
display: block;
border: 4px solid black;
max-width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
background: #FF7163;
padding: 40px;
outline: 4px dotted black;
outline-offset: 10px;

}
.introduction{

   font-size: 1.5em;
   line-height: 25px;
   margin-bottom: 20px;

}

h3{

 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

button{

    width: 100px;

}

.question,#score{

  font-size: 1.5em;

}
.inputs{

  
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.8em;


}

label{

  margin-left: 10px;

}
input[type='radio']{

   margin-left: 60px;




}

 input[type='radio']:after {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        top: -3px;
        left: -1px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #d1d3d1;
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        visibility: visible;
        border: 2px solid white;

    }

    input[type='radio']:checked:after {
        width: 15px;
        height: 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        top: -2px;
        left: -1px;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #4F8ABF;
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        visibility: visible;
        border: 2px solid white;
    }


    .image{
     
    
      max-width: 80px;
      margin-top: 50px;
  

    }

    .correct, .wrong,.result{

       display: none;


    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
 <title>Quiz Game</title>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <header class="row">
   <div class="col">
    <h1>Quiz Game</h1>
   </div>
  </header><!-- /header -->
  <main class="row contenedor">
   <div class="col">
    <div class="row question">
     <div class="col-12">
      <h3 id="title"></h3>
     </div>
     <div class="col-12">
      <p class="redact" id="redact"></p>
     </div>
     <div class="row p-0">
      <div class=" col-8 p-0 inputs">
       <input id="answer1" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="1"><label class="select" for="answer1"><span id="option1"></span></label><br>
       <input id="answer2" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="2"><label class="select" for="answer2"><span id="option2"></span></label><br>
       <input id="answer3" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="3"><label class="select" for="answer3"><span id="option3"></span></label><br>
       <input id="answer4" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="4"><label class="select" for="answer4"><span id="option4"></span></label>
      </div>
      <div class=" col-4 p-0 images"><img alt="correct" class="image correct" id="correct" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/D/1/e/4/N/X/ok-button-md.png"> <img alt="correct" class="image wrong" id="wrong" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/13/10/33/cross-157492_960_720.png"></div>
      <div class="col-12">
       <p id="message"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
       <button class=" btn btn-danger mt-4 check" id="check">Check!</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
       <button class=" btn btn-outline-dark mt-4  next" id="next" class="result">Next!</button>
      </div>
      
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col result" id="result">
       
                            <h2>Thanks For play</h2> 
                            <p id="score"></p>

      </div>
    <div id="first">
     <h2>Welcome to Quiz Game</h2>
     <p class="introduction">The game consists of answering the questions that will appear as you answer, once you have finished answering, you will get your results</p>
     <h3>ARE YOU READY?</h3><button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" id="start">Start!</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </main>
 </div>
 <script src="js/index.js">
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: anexa por favor el error exacto que te devuelve la consola

Comment: si ya lo edite que pena

Comment: ¿que intentas hacer con esta linea: `let quest= fill[index];`?. Al parecer ahí esta la raíz del problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error básicamente está en que al método `arrays` le está pasando un indice fuera del rango lo cuál al intentar acceder `fill[index];` retorna `undefined` lo que conlleva a no poder acceder a las propiedades del objeto.

Además está concatenando `listeners` en cada acción de `click` sobre el botón `next`, en la línea `next.addEventListener('click` lo cuál es incorrecto, el evento es siempre para el mismo elemento por lo tanto debería hacerse desde fuera de la función y ahí tener la validación para saber cuando ejecutar una u otra acción mediante una comparación `if(actualQuestion === numQuestions){`

Desde la función solo se cambiaría el `textContent` del botón , las acciones en el listener, además algunas variables las referencié a los elementos correspondientes fuera de las funciones

```js
var fill= [{

 "title":"QUESTION 1",
 "question": "The first mechanical computer designed by charles was called ?",
 "option1": "Abacus",
 "option2": "Processor",
 "option3": "System",
 "option4": "truue",
 "answer": "1"
}, {
    "title":"QUESTION 2",
 "question": "Which of the following is the most powerful type of computter",
 "option1": "Supermicro",
 "option2": "Supercomputer",
 "option3": "Superconductor",
 "option4": "Megaframe",
 "answer": "2"
},
{

    "title":"QUESTION 3",
 "question": "The first mechanical computer designed by charles was called ?",
 "option1": "Abacus",
 "option2": "Processor",
 "option3": "System",
 "option4": "truue",
 "answer": "3"
}, {

 "title":"QUESTION 4",
 "question": "Which of the following is the most powerful type of compuuter",
 "option1": "Supermicro",
 "option2": "Supercomputer",
 "option3": "Superconductor",
 "option4": "Megaframe", 
 "answer": "1"
},
{

 "title":"QUESTION 5",
 "question": "Which of the following is the most powerful type of compuuter",
 "option1": "Supermicro",
 "option2": "Supercomputer",
 "option3": "Superconductor",
 "option4": "Megaframe",
 "answer": "1"
}
]

/*this remove the the start of quiz and change color to principal contain*/
//variables contain
//

let imageCorrect = document.getElementById("correct");
let imageWrong= document.getElementById("wrong");

let body       = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let first      = document.getElementById("first");
let contenedor = document.getElementsByClassName("contenedor")[0];
let question   = document.getElementsByClassName("question")[0];
let title      = document.getElementById("title");
let paragraph  = document.getElementById("redact");
let option1    = document.getElementById("option1");
let option2    = document.getElementById("option2");
let option3    = document.getElementById("option3");
let option4    = document.getElementById("option4");
let message    = document.getElementById("message");
let button     = document.getElementById("start");
let check      = document.getElementById("check");
let next       = document.getElementById("next");
let input = document.querySelectorAll('.inputs input[type="radio"]');

let actualQuestion = 0;
let points         = 0;
let numQuestions   = fill.length;

body.addEventListener('load',start(),false);

function start(){
 question.style.display = 'none';
 // listener button
 button.addEventListener('click',function(){
  first.style.display = 'none';
  contenedor.style.background = '#FFA54F';
  question.style.display = 'block';
  next.disabled=true;

 });
}

function arrays(index){
  let quest= fill[index];
  title.textContent= quest.title;
  paragraph.textContent= quest.question;
  option1.textContent= quest.option1;
  option2.textContent= quest.option2;
  option3.textContent= quest.option3;
  option4.textContent= quest.option4;
}

function nextQuestion(){
 let choose = document.querySelector('input[type=radio]:checked');
 if(!choose){
   message.style.display = 'block';
   message.textContent= "Please answer the question";
   message.style.marginTop="20px";
   message.style.fontSize= "0.8em"; 
 }
 else{
  let value = choose.value;
  if(fill[actualQuestion].answer==value){
     imageCorrect.style.display="block";
     disabledInputs()

     points+=20;
  }else{
     imageWrong.style.display = 'block';
     disabledInputs()
  }

  if((choose.checked)){
     message.style.display ="none";
     next.disabled=false;
  }

  choose.checked=false;
  actualQuestion++;
  if(actualQuestion === numQuestions ){
   next.textContent="Result";
      
  }
 }
}
next.addEventListener('click',function(){
 if(actualQuestion === numQuestions){
     let result = document.getElementById("result");
  let score = document.getElementById("score");
  question.style.display = 'none';
  contenedor.style.background="#FFAE75";
  result.style.display="block";
  score.textContent="Your score "+points;
 }
 else{
  next.disabled=true;
  imageWrong.style.display="none";
  imageCorrect.style.display="none";
  activeInputs()
  arrays(actualQuestion);
 }
})

function disabledInputs(){
   for(let i=0 ; i<input.length;i++){
  input[i].disabled=true;  
 }
}
function activeInputs(){
 for(let i=0 ; i<input.length;i++){
    input[i].disabled=false;
 }
}
arrays(actualQuestion);

check.addEventListener('click',nextQuestion)
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt|VT323');

h1{

font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
font-size: 3em;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E5A46A, grey);
margin: 0;
margin-bottom: 50px;
padding: 20px 10px;
}

h2{
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 3em;
margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.contenedor{

font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
display: block;
border: 4px solid black;
max-width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
background: #FF7163;
padding: 40px;
outline: 4px dotted black;
outline-offset: 10px;

}
.introduction{
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h3{

font-weight: bold;
font-size: 2em;
margin-bottom: 30px;
}

button{

width: 100px;

}

.question,#score{
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
.inputs{
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

label{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
input[type='radio']{
  margin-left: 60px;
}

input[type='radio']:after {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: -3px;
    left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #d1d3d1;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    border: 2px solid white;

}

input[type='radio']:checked:after {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: -2px;
    left: -1px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #4F8ABF;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: visible;
    border: 2px solid white;
}


.image{
  max-width: 80px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.correct, .wrong,.result{
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
 <header class="row">
  <div class="col">
   <h1>Quiz Game</h1>
  </div>
 </header><!-- /header -->
 <main class="row contenedor">
  <div class="col">
   <div class="row question">
    <div class="col-12">
     <h3 id="title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
     <p class="redact" id="redact"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row p-0">
     <div class=" col-8 p-0 inputs">
      <input id="answer1" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="1"><label class="select" for="answer1"><span id="option1"></span></label><br>
      <input id="answer2" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="2"><label class="select" for="answer2"><span id="option2"></span></label><br>
      <input id="answer3" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="3"><label class="select" for="answer3"><span id="option3"></span></label><br>
      <input id="answer4" name="select" class="selects" type="radio" value="4"><label class="select" for="answer4"><span id="option4"></span></label>
     </div>
     <div class=" col-4 p-0 images"><img alt="correct" class="image correct" id="correct" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/D/1/e/4/N/X/ok-button-md.png"> <img alt="correct" class="image wrong" id="wrong" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/13/10/33/cross-157492_960_720.png"></div>
     <div class="col-12">
      <p id="message"></p>
     </div>
     <div class="col-6">
      <button class=" btn btn-danger mt-4 check" id="check">Check!</button>
     </div>
     <div class="col-6">
      <button class=" btn btn-outline-dark mt-4  next" id="next" class="result">Next!</button>
     </div>
     
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col result" id="result">
      
                        <h2>Thanks For play</h2> 
                        <p id="score"></p>

     </div>
   <div id="first">
    <h2>Welcome to Quiz Game</h2>
    <p class="introduction">The game consists of answering the questions that will appear as you answer, once you have finished answering, you will get your results</p>
    <h3>ARE YOU READY?</h3><button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" id="start">Start!</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Dev joel muchisimas gracias enserio te agradezco un monton , mira soy nivel principiante y no podia saber que era intente muchas cosas y no me funcionaba , solo queda agradecerte ojala te pudiera dar muchisimos votos